# How to make tests for scripts that access a serial port

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, pyserial, nose

I am developing a package that connects to an external device to ask to do some functions. For instance, a sample script of the package could be the following:

```
from serial import Serial
import glob

class SerialComm():
    def __init__(self)
        # Do some stuff
        # ...
        self.port = glob.glob('/dev/ttyUSB*')[0]
        self.serial = Serial(port=self.port)

    def ask_if_ready(port, baudrate):
        """Send an acknowledge request through serial port."""
        message = SerialComm.build_message(function='ready')
        my_serial = Serial(port=port, baudrate=baudrate)
        my_serial.write(message) 
        return my_serial.read()

    def build_message(function):
        """Makes a message based on a protocol"""
        #Do stuff
        return message
```

I would like to write some tests to assess the code, and I would like this test to be autonomous and do not depend on whether there is a device connected to the PC or not. However, if there is not any device connected, the previous code will crash before any assertion could be made (glob.glob() function and serial functions require some device connected).

I can not figure out how to trick the code in order to simulate the behaviour of a device connected to a serial port and test the different methods of my class.

Comment: You are looking for [mocking](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). Mocking serial connection is not that different than mocking anything else.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski please write a real answer. Don't use the comments to answer the question.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski I have been reading a bit about mocking before asking, but I have not seen any example similar to managing serial ports, so I would appreciate an aclaration

Comment: You can use pseudoterminal which simulate the serial port on the linux for mocking it .
[Mocking Serial Port](http://allican.be/blog/2017/01/15/python-dummy-serial-port.html)

Comment: @DeepakKapoor While that script does something, I'm not sure how to integrate that into a proper unittest. Surely some part of it should go in a setUp method, and the listener will run in the test script. So far I get 0 tests run, when I try that...

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Being rather new to unittests in Python, I wonder how unittest.mock is to be used here. Are all calls to the serial port to be replaced? How so? I would like to leave my code unchanged and do the testing in a seperate script.  Please clarify